# PHP function wont save variables

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function findSchedule($team)
{
    switch($team)
    {
        case "Baltimore Orioles":

        $team_home[42] = "Tampa Bay Rays";
        $team_home[43] = "Boston Red Sox";
        $team_home[44] = "Boston Red Sox";
        $team_home[45] = "$team";
        $team_home[46] = "$team";
        $team_home[47] = "$team";
        $team_home[48] = "$team";

        $team_away[42] = "$team";
        $team_away[43] = "$team";
        $team_away[44] = "$team";
        $team_away[45] = "New York Yankees";
        $team_away[46] = "New York Yankees";
        $team_away[47] = "Washington Nationals";
        $team_away[48] = "Washington Nationals";

        $team_date[42] = "Sun, May 15";
        $team_date[43] = "Mon, May 16";
        $team_date[44] = "Tue, May 17";
        $team_date[45] = "Wed, May 18";
        $team_date[46] = "Thu, May 19";
        $team_date[47] = "Fri, May 20";
        $team_date[48] = "Sat, May 21";

        break;

        case "Boston Red Sox":

        $team_home[42] = "$team";
        $team_home[43] = "$team";
        $team_home[44] = "$team";
        $team_home[45] = "$team";
        $team_home[46] = "$team";
        $team_home[47] = "$team";
        $team_home[48] = "$team";

        $team_away[42] = "Baltimore Orioles";
        $team_away[43] = "Baltimore Orioles";
        $team_away[44] = "Detroit Tigers";
        $team_away[45] = "Detroit Tigers";
        $team_away[46] = "Chicago Cubs";
        $team_away[47] = "Chicago Cubs";
        $team_away[48] = "Chicago Cubs";

        $team_date[42] = "Mon, May 16";
        $team_date[43] = "Tue, May 17";
        $team_date[44] = "Wed, May 18";
        $team_date[45] = "Thu, May 19";
        $team_date[46] = "Fri, May 20";
        $team_date[47] = "Sat, May 21";
        $team_date[48] = "Sun, May 22";

        break;
  }

  for($i = 42;$i < 49;++$i)
  {
    return $team_home[$i];
    return $team_away[$i];
    return $team_date[$i];
  }
```

When I try to use the $team_date, $team_away, and $team_home variables as follows, the only one that seems to work is the $team_home variable.

```
$game = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'game', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$team_home[$game] = findSchedule($team);
$team_away[$game] = findSchedule($team);
$team_date[$game] = findSchedule($team);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but if you're using that `switch` statement to handle more than two teams, then this really sounds like a job where a database would come in handy...

Comment: Yeah, it's actually 30 teams. But, I don't really want to put too much strain on the DB. But, do you think it would be more efficient to rely on a DB than php in this case?

Comment: 30 teams won't put a strain on your database. Try 30 million or so :)

Comment: Awesome. I just might switch to utilizing mysql a bit more. on a side note, is it generally bad practice to use more than 3 queries per page? will that decrease the load time by quite a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with how you constructed your final `for` loop. You have it set to [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) each value; the `return` statement ends processing. You want to `echo` each one and then return, or alternatively never explicitly state `return` but just end the function.

To return all arguments, you could just make a single, larger array and return that:

```
return array( $team_home, $team_away, $team_date);
```

Comment: Well, how can I save the values of what's in the arrays without returning them?

Answer (score 1):

On the returning side you write an array:

```
return array($team_home, $team_away, $team_date);
```

And on the receiving side you can use `list()`:

```
list($team_home, $team_away, $team_date) = findSchedule($team);
```